# Conversion of geo coordinates from degree-hour-minutes to decimal in XSL

Tags: xslt, coordinate-systems, geography

I have a XML file where one of the element is Geo-coordinate (Latitude/Longitude). This field is in degree-hour-minutes(eg: 43:06:35.4779) format and I need to convert it to decimal format. Can anyone help to do this conversion in XSL or point to some materials. Thanks in advance!

Edits: Can anyone help me to truncate the lat/long value I get after conversion. eg

```
<latitude>43.051643999999996</latitude>
<longitude>-112.62663475000001</longitude>
```

Comment: Do you mean from degrees (0 to +-180) to radians (-pi  to pi)? Or just from 43:06:35 to  43.109855 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="lat/text() | long/text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="DegreesToDecimal"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="DegreesToDecimal">
  <xsl:param name="pDegrees" select="."/>

  <xsl:variable name="vDegrees" select=
   "number(substring-before($pDegrees, ':'))"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vMinutes" select=
   "number(
       substring-before(
           substring-after($pDegrees, ':'),
           ':'
                       )
           )"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vSeconds" select=
   "number(
       substring-after(
           substring-after($pDegrees, ':'),
           ':'
                       )
           )"/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "$vDegrees
  +
    $vMinutes div 60
  +
    $vSeconds div 3600
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<coordinates>
 <lat>43:06:35.4779</lat>
 <long>53:22:16.7890</long>
</coordinates>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<coordinates>
   <lat>43.10985497222222</lat>
   <long>53.37133027777778</long>
</coordinates>
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of the `substring-before()`, `substring-after()` and `number()` functions.

Comment: When I use this code I get <lat>NaN</lat> <long>NaN</long>. What might be the issue? Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Comment: @mona: Either you modified the XSLT code or the XML document, or you have a buggy, non-compliant XSLT processor. I work with 9+ different XSLT processors and all of them produce the same, correct result.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I wasn't sure how to traverse an XML tree. so messed up..It works good!

Comment: Dimitre,how can I truncate the lat/long value I get?

Comment: @Mona: one way is to use the `format-number()` function. How many digits after the decimal point do you need?